# When is ContextRefreshedEvent fired in Spring?

Tags: spring

I know that it is fired once when the ApplicationContext is fully loaded, but what about after that during runtime? The word "Refreshed" implies that it will be triggered on a refresh but I wonder what Spring qualifies as an ApplicationContext refresh?

Followup question:
Can this event be triggered by concurrent threads? Do I need to make the EventHandler for this event thread safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is fired when properties, xml or any schema files are loaded/refreshed, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh--

> Load or refresh the persistent representation of the configuration,
>   which might an XML file, properties file, or relational database
>   schema.

It is fired implicitly by spring usually, but you should be able to fire that on certain instances, But here is java doc says when that happens

> As this is a startup method, it should destroy already created
>   singletons if it fails, to avoid dangling resources. In other words,
>   after invocation of that method, either all or no singletons at all
>   should be instantiated.

Comment: I see. Does this lend itself to being tiggered by two different threads simultaneously?

Comment: Not sure on that, even if it possible i would not do that. You have one application context and if you refresh it from two different threads you in trouble

Comment: For the database, is it triggered when the application attempts to connect to a database?