# Understanding Spring Boot's App Lifecycle and Startup Listeners

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Sprint Boot 2.x we can initialize our application in one of 2 approaches:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Init the app from in here...
    }
}
```

Or we can use a startup listener that will execute on startup:

```java
public class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Init the app from in here...
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what tradeoffs exist by taking either approach. Not knowing much about Spring Boot's "app lifecycle", I'm wondering if there are things I will/won't have access to in either setup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about init method without `@PostConstruct` annotation?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski Notice that the `init` method is explicitly called by the `main` method.

Comment: If so I don't think that a good way to initialize Spring boot application. Don't know when `run` method returns. Better to make `init` public and annotate with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski what `run` method are you talking about here?

Comment: `SpringApplication.run`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `init` method is only called after startup, and is only called when running your application as a command-line program.

The `init` method is e.g. not called when deploying your application as a .war file.

The `onApplicationEvent` method is called whenever a [`ContextRefreshedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) is fired, which does happen during startup, but can be called again later. See e.g. "[When is ContextRefreshedEvent fired in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39934919/5221149)"

For a more comparable event to the `init` method, use [`ApplicationStartedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationStartedEvent.html).